# empty list when I scrape a table using findparent and findAll

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project to scrape the daily population of some servers in a game to see how they evolve. It's a table where each server is a 'tr' that contains several 'td' inside with information such as the number of players and also useless information. The thing is that I managed to pick up all the 'tr' I'm interested in, discarding the ones I don't want, but now I'm stuck trying to select only the 'td' inside each 'tr' that has the number of players, but I can't.

this is the table:
[image: this is the table]

this is the html of that table:
[image: this is the html of that table]

This is the code I've written so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import date

url = ('https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds')
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
file = open('players_online', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file)

list_of_players = list()
finding_td = soup.find_all('a', string=worlds)
for looking_for_players in finding_td:
    parent_tr = looking_for_players.find_parent('tr')
    names1 = [clean_data.findAll('td') for clean_data in parent_tr]
    list_of_players.append(parent_tr)
```

If I print 'print(finding_td) I get the following:

```
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Astera">Astera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Belobra">Belobra</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Calmera">Calmera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Celebra">Celebra</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Gentebra">Gentebra</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Kalibra">Kalibra</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Luminera">Luminera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Menera">Menera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Nefera">Nefera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Pacera">Pacera</a>, 
<a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Yonabra">Yonabra</a>]
```

which is what I want, now I use the findparent and when I **'print(finding_tr)** I get:

```
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Belobra">Belobra</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">731</td><td>South America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since June 22, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Calmera">Calmera</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">318</td><td>North America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since September 12, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Celebra">Celebra</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">559</td><td>South America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since October 29, 2018.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Odd"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Gentebra">Gentebra</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">757</td><td>South America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since December 12, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Kalibra">Kalibra</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">716</td><td>South America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since December 12, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Odd"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Luminera">Luminera</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">295</td><td>North America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since September 5, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Menera">Menera</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">364</td><td>North America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since September 5, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Nefera">Nefera</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">465</td><td>North America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since April 19, 2018.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Odd"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Pacera">Pacera</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">336</td><td>North America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since September 12, 2017.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Even"><td style="width: 150px;"><a href="https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&amp;world=Yonabra">Yonabra</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">446</td><td>South America</td><td>Optional PvP</td><td align="center" valign="middle"> <span style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><a href="../common/help.php?subtopic=battleye" target="_blank"><span class="HelperDivIndicator" onmouseout="$('#HelperDivContainer').hide();" onmouseover="ActivateHelperDiv($(this), 'BattlEye Protected Game World', '&lt;p&gt;On this game world, BattlEye blocks cheats from the game. The game world has been protected by BattlEye since May 27, 2020.&lt;/p&gt;', '');"><img src="https://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/icon_battleye.gif" style="border: 0px;"/></span></a></span></td><td></td></tr>
```

so far so good, now that I have all the td, I want to make a line to select only the td which contains the number of players, I did it as follows:

```
names1 = [clean_data.findAll('td') for clean_data in parent_tr]
```

but when I append it or print it, it gives this:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

And if I use ***names1 = [clean_data.find('td')[3] for clean_data in parent_tr]*** to find the specific 'td' which contains the data I want, the console says:

> **"IndexError: list index out of range"**.

That makes sense because its an empty list after all. Any idea of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get names and population of every regular world, you can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select(".TableContent")[2].select("td > a"):
    name = a.get_text(strip=True)
    pop = a.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)

    print("{:<30} {}".format(name, pop))
```

Prints:

```
Adra                           54
Antica                         271
Assombra                       166
Astera                         419
Belluma                        18
Belobra                        743
Bona                           150
Calmera                        326
Carnera                        73
Celebra                        560
Celesta                        82
Concorda                       51
Cosera                         103
Damora                         89
Descubra                       524
Dibra                          379
Duna                           6
Emera                          70
Epoca                          23
Estela                         129
Faluna                         24
Ferobra                        599
Firmera                        180
Funera                         83
Furia                          14
Garnera                        299
Gentebra                       769
Gladera                        464
Harmonia                       112
Helera                         55
Honbra                         629
Impera                         340
Inabra                         636
Javibra                        229
Jonera                         131
Kalibra                        700
Karna                          175
Kenora                         90
Libertabra                     364
Lobera                         473
Luminera                       293
Lutabra                        469
Macabra                        277
Menera                         365
Mitigera                       100
Monza                          112
Mudabra                        427
Nefera                         475
Noctera                        195
Nossobra                       252
Olera                          87
Ombra                          601
Optera                         186
Pacembra                       402
Pacera                         352
Peloria                        226
Premia                         74
Pyra                           4
Quelibra                       578
Quintera                       280
Ragna                          15
Refugia                        103
Reinobra                       555
Relania                        54
Relembra                       330
Secura                         175
Serdebra                       606
Serenebra                      394
Solidera                       395
Talera                         538
Torpera                        102
Tortura                        25
Unica                          13
Utobra                         355
Venebra                        485
Vita                           31
Vunira                         154
Wintera                        415
Wizera                         209
Xandebra                       528
Xylona                         16
Yonabra                        419
Ysolera                        87
Zenobra                        281
Zuna                           3
Zunera                         39
```

---

Or: select all links and check if text of previous header is "Regular Worlds":

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select(".TableContent td > a"):
    # check if we are in "Regular Worlds" table:
    header = a.find_previous("td", {"style": "text-align: center;"})
    if header.get_text(strip=True) != "Regular Worlds":
        continue

    name = a.get_text(strip=True)
    pop = a.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)

    print("{:<30} {}".format(name, pop))
```

Comment: Actually brilliant, thank you for sharing.